# post a photo comment using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I can post a standard comment to a post I created with the SDK but I can't post a photo comment, how is this done?

I tried sending the URL of the photo as the 'attachment' , it didn't work

I then uploaded the photo with status of 0 for 'published' and sent the ID of that photo as the 'attachment' but no go

this is my code snippet

```
try {
    $photo = $facebook ->api('/'.$c['active']['id'].'/photos','post',array(

        'url'=>$_REQUEST['picture'],
        'published'=> 0,
        'no_story' => 0,
        'access_token' => $c['active']['access_token']
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
if($photo['id']){
    try{
        $facebook ->api('/'.$status['id'].'/comments', 
            'post', 
            array(
                'access_token' => $c['active']['access_token'],
                'message' => ':)',
                'attachment'=> 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$photo['id']
            )
        );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e){
        echo '<h2>Had an error updating the comment '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I get an ID for the photo and can see it was uploaded and the comment posts but it does not have the image attached.

how can a photo comment be made with PHP SDK?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Using graph api explorer gives an error that you must provide message or attachment_id, but there is nothing on how to add attachment or how to use it.

Comment: No sorry, I was not able to find any documentation at all on it

Answer (score 0):

The code need to be updated slightly to allow you to post a photo with the comment:

First off, the attachment you are trying to add is a page not a image. You should link directly to the jpg / png / gif file. Second, you should use attachment_url if you are linking to an already uploaded image. Here is a working example:

```
$facebook ->api('/'.$status['id'].'/comments', 'post', 
  array(
    'access_token' => $c['active']['access_token'],
    'message' => ':)',
    'attachment_url'=> 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t31.0-8/p960x960/10011994_10100351413566796_479698704_o.jpg'
  )
);
```

Use `source` if you intend to upload a image and post it as a comment. More information can be [found here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/03/26/facebook-api-posting-a-comment-with-photo/).